# More about Problems with using esp8266

Tags: esp8266

I'm running a project under https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AL7HfiRlp4&t=23s
I encounter a problem with "deadly error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory", the code indicates '' #include  ''.
I read a conversation between John Romkey and Thonka on July 5th '18. I've deleted all libraries that mention esp8266, esp32 and wifi. But from the conversation I don't know what libraries I have to use now? I use the following code:

```
/* 
 * Mert Arduino and Tech - YouTube
 * WiFi Robot controlled by Phone (WiFibot/Android/IoT/ESP8266)
 * NodeMCU ESP8266 Tutorial 03
 * Please Subscribe for Support - https://goo.gl/RLT6DT
 */


/* include library */
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

/*
 * If you have no idea about this library, you can watch the tutorial below
 * NodeMCU ESP8266 Tutorial 01: Programming NodeMCU ESP-12E Using Arduino IDE
 * https://youtu.be/NtyFx1frYB0
 */

/* define port */
WiFiClient client;
WiFiServer server(80);

/* WIFI settings */
const char* ssid = "YOUR SSID";
const char* password = "YOUR PASSWORD";

/* data received from application */
String  data =""; 

/* define L298N or L293D motor control pins */
int leftMotorForward = 2;     /* GPIO2(D4) -> IN3   */
int rightMotorForward = 15;   /* GPIO15(D8) -> IN1  */
int leftMotorBackward = 0;    /* GPIO0(D3) -> IN4   */
int rightMotorBackward = 13;  /* GPIO13(D7) -> IN2  */


/* define L298N or L293D enable pins */
int rightMotorENB = 14; /* GPIO14(D5) -> Motor-A Enable */
int leftMotorENB = 12;  /* GPIO12(D6) -> Motor-B Enable */

void setup()
{
  /* initialize motor control pins as output */
  pinMode(leftMotorForward, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rightMotorForward, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(leftMotorBackward, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(rightMotorBackward, OUTPUT);

  /* initialize motor enable pins as output */
  pinMode(leftMotorENB, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(rightMotorENB, OUTPUT);

  /* start server communication */
  server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    /* If the server available, run the "checkClient" function */  
    client = server.available();
    if (!client) return; 
    data = checkClient ();

/************************ Run function according to incoming data from application *************************/

    /* If the incoming data is "forward", run the "MotorForward" function */
    if (data == "forward") MotorForward();
    /* If the incoming data is "backward", run the "MotorBackward" function */
    else if (data == "backward") MotorBackward();
    /* If the incoming data is "left", run the "TurnLeft" function */
    else if (data == "left") TurnLeft();
    /* If the incoming data is "right", run the "TurnRight" function */
    else if (data == "right") TurnRight();
    /* If the incoming data is "stop", run the "MotorStop" function */
    else if (data == "stop") MotorStop();
} 

/********************************************* FORWARD *****************************************************/
void MotorForward(void)   
{
  digitalWrite(leftMotorENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorForward,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorForward,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorBackward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorBackward,LOW);
}

/********************************************* BACKWARD *****************************************************/
void MotorBackward(void)   
{
  digitalWrite(leftMotorENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorBackward,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorBackward,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorForward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorForward,LOW);
}

/********************************************* TURN LEFT *****************************************************/
void TurnLeft(void)   
{
  digitalWrite(leftMotorENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorENB,HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(leftMotorForward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorForward,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorBackward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorBackward,HIGH);  
}

/********************************************* TURN RIGHT *****************************************************/
void TurnRight(void)   
{
  digitalWrite(leftMotorENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorENB,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorForward,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorForward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorBackward,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorBackward,LOW);
}

/********************************************* STOP *****************************************************/
void MotorStop(void)   
{
  digitalWrite(leftMotorENB,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorENB,LOW);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorForward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(leftMotorBackward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorForward,LOW);
  digitalWrite(rightMotorBackward,LOW);
}

/********************************** RECEIVE DATA FROM the APP ******************************************/
String checkClient (void)
{
  while(!client.available()) delay(1); 
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  request.remove(0, 5);
  request.remove(request.length()-9,9);
  return request;
}
```

Comment: install esp8266 boards package https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino#installing-with-boards-manager

Comment: I installed it. Anyway #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>. ''ESP8266WiFi.h:No such file or directory''

Comment: did you select an esp8266 board in tools menu?

Comment: yes, many boards

Comment: reinstall esp8266 boards package

Comment: OK!!! I was a bad installer